# I'm trying to program my first Discord bot, but it’s not responding to the command (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been following a video on how to code commands for beginners.
I tried this code, but it's not responding to the command I checked the permissions no issues there as well. I copied his code all the same and did not also work.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online');

    const token = ' Token ';
});

const PREFIX = '!';

client.on('message ', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]) {
        case 'ping':
            message.reply('pong!');
        break;
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You're never actually checking if they use the prefix, so, once functional, this will respond to any single character + `ping`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```js
client.on('message', //rest of code
```

instead of

```js
client.on('message ', //rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to adjust the permissions in your client's declaration.

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

then I would try changing the event listener, the last version deprecated some old events

try

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {

  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch(args[0]){
    case 'ping':
      message.reply('pong!');
    break;

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I checked your code right now and since you're only running a few commands and nothing crazily advanced, I'd suggest just using an if statement to check the content of the message and IF It meets the condition to return something, here's the code that I tested and It works, It's a lot simpler and easily modifiable.
I'd also suggest adjusting the Intents like Armandas Astrauskas said, and you shouldn't declare stuff inside client methods, like the `ready` one where you declared the token in, AND if you're using discord.js v13 you'd have to use [messageCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate).

```
const {Client,Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();
const token = ' Token ';


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('bot is online');
});


const PREFIX = '!';


client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content == `${PREFIX}ping`) {
    message.reply("pong!")
  }

})

client.login(token);
```